# Декоратор на несколько методов

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, декоратор

У меня есть класс-компонент с одним методом, класс оборачивается в несколько декораторов. Декораторы наподобие логирования не изменяют результат метода.

Нужно добавить новый метод в компонент.

Вопрос в следующем: во всех описаниях декоратором оборачивается класс с целью расширения функциональности определенного метода (например, для класса Book создается BookTitleDecorator), можно ли расширить интерфейс существующих декораторов новым методом или это будет нарушением паттерна "Декоратор" и нужно под каждый метод писать свои декораторы?

Comment: Декоратор совершенно не обязан оборачивать только один метод. Весь старый I/O в Java сделан на декораторах, для примера.

Comment: Декорируют, вроде, _класс_ (_объект_), а не отдельную функцию

Comment: если вы в базовый класс вносите новый функционал, то конечно стоит  и в декораторах его учесть. но это не обязательно

Comment: то что вы хотите сделать, легко делается при помощи аспектов. посмотрите на них.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае декоратор это класс, реализующий такой же интерфейс, как и декорируемый класс. Он делегирует основной функционал во всех методах декорируемому классу и дополнительно совершает какие-то свои действия. Ключевой момент здесь в том, что он не ограничен каким-то одним методом, но должен быть ограничен какой-то одной целью (см. [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). Таким образом он может добавить логирование во все методы.

Если же мы хотим, чтобы происходило что-то принципиально другое (например, вызов каких-то событий) при вызове методов, необходимо создать еще один декоратор и обернуть экземпляр в оба декоратора.

Порядок оборачивания имеет значение. Он влияет на последовательность исполнения логики декораторов.